# Disable Scroll with dynamic content when its not necessary

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a page with a section of tabs in which each one of these tabs has more or less content and when I open a tab with a lot of content and then I go to a tab with less content the page keeps allowing scroll (even it the page is empty), I've just found answers about when the content grows up but nothing about when it shrinks out.

What I want to achieve is to be able to scroll when there is a lot of content on the screen and use just the view height when there is little content on the screen.

This is the basic scheme of the page

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
}
.footer{
  position:relative;
  bottom:0;
}
```

This is how it looks when I open a lot of content and then a little:
[image]

Comment: what do u want to do? clarify more about your problem

Comment: I've already edited the post. Basically I want the scroll bar to be in accordance with the content of the page

Answer (score 0):

add `max-width: 100vw;` to your overflowing element replace `100vw` with ur value

Comment: To which tag? I've added it to html, body and the content div but it doesn't work. The problem is when the content is big and then it shrinks

Comment: edited. it would be nice if you could add more code